# Why is the difference function in QGIS not giving a clean cut?

Tags: vector, difference, qgis

I used Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Difference function in QGIS to obtain difference between two vectors (Shown as vectors - overall and polygon in the figure below). But the difference is not clean. There is a intersection between polygon and the difference layer. Is there a way to have a clean cut?

[image]

Comment: No, that is the way those functions are designed to work.

Comment: @IanTurton so the difference between two layers will have an intersection? Any other way to get a clean cut?

Comment: the shared boundary of two polygons will always intersect - I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @IanTurton the intersection came out as a polygon as u can see in the legend. So, I reckoned they were polygons but I guess they are lines as you say - the shared boundary!